# Achieve different code folding in HTML

Tags: sublimetext3, code-folding

When I collapse code in Sublime Text 3 I get this:

```
<div>...
</div>
```

When I would much rather have this:

```
<div>...</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime folds code by showing you the first line of the block followed by the little yellow box containing an ellipsis, hides the rest, and shows either the final line of the block or the beginning of the next block, depending on indentation level. It does not move code elements around or onto new lines. This behavior is not user-modifiable.